# All latitude and longitude within 1 mile circle area

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

I am trying to generate pins over the map of my database coordinates by using fusion table and I want to generate only within 1 mile area circle around the specific location. To get 1 mile area's coordinates similar to my db coordinates I've to put condition of < and > to fusion table but I don't know how to get all the coordinates within 1 mile area circle or what should be the value for condition in query. Can any one please help me to figure out, it'll really appreciable.

Comment: You need 1) a bounding box, 2) a distance function, 3) a simple loop. Which of these can you do, and which do you need help with?

Comment: Thanks for responding Beta, I can do only loop part :) but I can do rest 2 part if I can get proper directions on how to do that

Comment: [Check this example](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/samples/rectangle_example) that defines a `RECTANGLE` and uses `ST_INTERSECTS` to find all records that are within this range. You could adapt the example to use a `CIRCLE` with a one mile radius.

Comment: Hi Odi, Thanks for such a helpful example. I am doing it with circle but I want all the lat/long within 1 mile area circle which is in FT. In rectangle they mention lowerleft and upperright to set limit but what and how to set limit in radius?

Comment: I think the answer from Eric is exactly what you need ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't provided any code, so I'm not exactly sure what you want to do. But the Fusion Table [ST_INTERSECTS](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/developers_reference#Select) operator should do what you want. Look for <spatial_condition>.

```
  var where = "ST_INTERSECTS('location_col',CIRCLE(LATLNG(31.954109,-115.441528), radius_in_meters) ) )";

  var qryOpts = {
   query: {
   select: location_col,
      from: table_id,
      where: where
    }
 };
 ft_layer.setOptions(qryOpts);
```

Comment: Hey Eric, I would like to thank you for replying with code :)

Comment: Hi Eric your answer is really nice but I want to generate selected points on map within 1 mile area which is on my database.

Comment: It's not clear to me what's in your database and what's in the Fusion Table. What is your database?

Comment: I do have coordinates(Lat/Lng) in my database. For example: "Aquitaine Boston" in Boston, MA is my center point of map and I want to display different types of parking places around the center point in circle of 1 mile area on click. I do have all the coordinates but it should display the pins which comes only in circle of 1 mile area.

Comment: You are still not providing enough information. How do you insert you database values into your html page?  PHP? Perl? ASP? Do you know how to create a FT layer?  The example Odi linked above shows how to do it but you need the Aquitane lat,lng in your web page first.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea if that is possible within the Fusion Tables API but, if I were doing it, I would first calculate which points in my database were within the radius and insert only those. You can ignore the earth's curvature and just use the Pythagorean theorem with a little adjusting for your latitude.

See here: http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

Comment: ...and use this to get the length in miles between degrees of latitude and longitude: http://www.csgnetwork.com/degreelenllavcalc.html . You need only approximations for purpose you described.